# WeChat admin can't login

Tags: wechat

I have built a chat bot for WeChat and connected it to a WeChat official page on https://admin.wechat.com

However, I can no longer login to the admin website. It gives invalid user/password, but I know they are correct. When I use the same user/password to check the account status it says the account is active.

Also if I try to reset the password it gives me the error "Server Busy", the same all week. It was working a few weeks ago.

I also tried login on https://mp.weixin.qq.com but I think you need a China account to connect to it?

Can anyone with an official WeChat account check if they can sign in?

Comment: You need to contact wechat admin team. Use the contact us button at their official website. I do have chinese and non-chinese accounts (verified) and able to login without any issues

Comment: I tried emailing support@wechat.com and bd@wechat.com but get no response...

Comment: Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a login page which works for me right now: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/debug/cgi-bin/sandbox?t=sandbox/login

It is for sandbox mode only, if you have official WeChat account, and wish to run your bot in production with full capabiities ensbled, you need to login differently.

You don't need a Chinese account to login to weixin sandbox.